# 'config' is not defined Pocketsphinx Python

Tags: python-3.x, pocketsphinx

I've imported the modules:

```
from pocketsphinx.pocketsphinx import *
from sphinxbase.sphinxbase import *
```

The LiveSpeech module is working and I am trying to disable the logs using:

```
config.set_string('-logfn', '/dev/null')
```

Although I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/pi/Downloads/Test.py", line 23, in config.set_string('-logfn', '/dev/null')
>
> NameError: name 'config' is not defined**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create config like this:

```
config = Decoder.default_config()
config.set_string('-logfn', '/dev/null')
decoder = Decoder(config)
```